# Sharepoint 2013 - Publish and Check in

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, publishing-site, publishing-page

I find myself publishing pages instead of checking them in over my website.

I know Check In and Check Out controls the editing documents and versions to avoid overwriting and file control and is visible only by those who have editing permissions

I know publishing publishes whatever the asset is - image, page, document, site etc. to a published major or minor version.

What I notice is if I publish it appears to do both - Check In the file and Publish the changes (according to the required need - major or minor).

What I would like to know are there implications if I do not check the page in - if I only publish? From the surface it does not appear apparent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a page is checked-out, the check-in and publish works as follows.

**Check-in:** Increments the page version. The new version is visible only to users who have Full Control access and above.

**Publish:**: Increments the page version by check-in automatically and visible to users who have Read access and above.